# Can't get classpath resource with spring ResourceUtils or DefaultResourceLoader in Docker env

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, classpath

I am developing a spring-boot web app, and i need to get some classpath resources, so i use the method below:

```
@Autowired
private Enviroment env;



 String fileLocation = ResourceUtils.getFile(env.getProperty("common.cert-location")).getAbsolutePath();
```

---

or

```
String fileLocation = new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource("filename").getFile().getPath();
```

Both of them run normally in the local enviroment, but when i pack the app and run it in a Docker image, it throw an exception. How can i get the resource? Thanks!

Comment: attach volume to container but give path relative to docker container.

Comment: @SJayesh thank you, i am rookie of docker, i used 'docker-maven-plugin' to run my app, and the volume in my Dockerfile is just '/tmp', so what's the relative path of 'src/main/resources' should be?

Comment: I never used 'docker-maven-plugin', but can you share the stack of exception(s).

Comment: @SJayesh Thanks, I have solved the problem by using "BaseController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you try to load a file from the filesystem. The file location is passed in using an environment variable.

If that is correct, you can add the file you need in your `Dockerfile` using `ADD myresource.file /myresource.file`. This puts `myresource.file` into the root of your container.

Now, if you run your container, you can pass your environment variable `common.cert-location` using `docker run -e common.cert-location=/myresource.file`.

One addition: you can add a Spring Boot application property instead of an environment variable. Then set an environment variable with the same name like your property in your container. Spring Boot should pick up the variable by default.

Instead of letting the container know the variable using the `-e` parameter, you can also use `env_file`. This allows you to put all your environment variables into a single file and push them into the container.

In combination with Spring Boot application properties, this allows you to override all application properties with environment variables defined in a single file. I think that is a nice, consistent way of configuring Boot apps inside containers.

Comment: I have solved the problem by using "BaseController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()‌​", Thanks,but I don't know why Spring ResourceUtils can't get the resource, i'll read the source code to find the reason, Thanks again